# Can autocompletion for inheritance in vscode auto-import types python?

Tags: python, inheritance, visual-studio-code, autocomplete, type-hinting

When using autocompletion for python in vscode in the case of overriding children methods, the autocompletion works nicely and writes all the types hints from the parent method.

However there are some typing hints that require imports.
Is it possible to setup automatic import for that in vscode, such that when autocompletion is used for that case, the types are auto-imported ?

See before autocompletion

[image: before autocompletion]

And after autocompletion, types are missing

[image: after autocompletion]

Answer (score 0):

With extension [My Code Actions](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=rioj7.my-code-actions) you can setup code actions to add imports based on the diagnostic messages (squiggles).

Add this to your `settings.json`

```json
"my-code-actions.actions": {
    "[python]": {
      "import {{diag:$1}}": {
        "diagnostics": ["\"(.*?)\" is not defined"],
        "text": "import {{diag:$1}}\n",
        "where": "afterLast",
        "insertFind": "^(import |from \\w+ import )"
      }
    }
  }
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but is this extension really legit ?
I ask that because there are very few downloads

Comment: @Lio this extension is pretty new, it takes some time to gain a few users, many people may be scared by the help page

Comment: Thanks, I installed the plugin, but I don't understand how to make it run right after I use the autocompletion, is it possible to do that ?